# snap application says it's up to date, but -v shows an older version

Tags: delete, installed-programs

the app in question is gallery-dl, and I had it installed via the snap store. a recent update of the app 1.23.1 -> 1.23.2 has some fixes to some issues i had.

I "sudo snap refresh gallery-dl" and it updated, on the store it showed the latest version was installed as well (1.23.2). however it still gave me issues and gallery-dl -v showed the older version.

what I did was unsitall from the snap store, (but i still somehow had the app, and -v stil showed the old version) and sudo apt remove gallery-dl. at that point i just reinstalled from the snap store and it works now.

as im really new to linux (always used windows+mac), can anyone give me any insight on this?
why were there multiple copies of the same app? (btw pip is not installed so i couldnt have installed with that command), how can i show them and delete a specific one?
so far my user experience is essentially blind googling command lines

Comment: Don't "*blind google command lines*." Take a moment to understand the command before you hit <enter>, Especially if it requires sudo! There's a lot of good advice out there...and a lot of bad advice, too.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses the Debian package management system, the APT system. In recent versions, an new packaging format, Snap, was introduced. Snap is aimed to work on most linux distributions, and also is containerized, removing the chance that malicious software could do much harm.

You have installed both an APT version and a Snap version of the same tool, `gallery-dl`. It is a command line tool, so does not have an icon in the launcher: you run it on the terminal by typing the name of the executable, `gallery-dl`.

When you type the name of an executable, the system will search all directories listed in the `PATH`variable for an executable with that name. You can see the variable in the output of `printenv PATH`. The executable of the APT version is installed in `/usr/bin`. The executable of the Snap version is installed in `/snap/bin`. In the `PATH` variable, the former comes before the latter, so it will be the instance in `/usr/bin` (the older version) that will be executed.

Removing one of the versions removes the ambiguity. Snap applications are removed with `snap remove ...`, APT application with `sudo apt remove ...`. Graphical applications may exist two times in the Ubuntu software center, once as a SNap and once as an APT.